# If A many-one reduces to B, does the complement of A many-one reduce to the complement of B?

Tags: complexity-theory, formal-languages, reductions

If A many-one reduces to B, does the complement of A many-one reduce to the complement of B? My gut says no but I am having a hard time finding a counterexample.

Comment: Try the following: write down what it means that $A\le_m B$, and what it means that $\overline{A}\le_m \overline{B}$. Then, see if you can find some connection between the two.

Comment: I know A < B means there is a map from A to B such that if x is in A then f(x) is in B.

Oh, wow, so that necessarily means if x isn't in A it is not in B, but that does not imply that there exists a function which maps all of x not in A to f(x) not in B.

Comment: The key point you are missing is the following. The definition is not just "if $x \in A$ then $f(x) \in B$", but "$x \in A$ if and only if $f(x)\in B$".

Answer (score 1):

Let's try an example. Here is a reduction from the set of even numbers to the set of squares: $x \mapsto 2^x$ (check it!). It is also a reduction from the set of odd numbers to the set of non-squares. Is that just by chance?

We can make the following twist: the mapping $x \mapsto 2^{x+1}$ maps the set of even numbers to the set of non-squares. Is it always the case that we can modify a reduction from $A$ to $B$ to a reduction from $A$ to $\overline{B}$?

Comment: If im getting this straight then you are saying that a map from A to B inadvertently maps compliment of A to compliment of B? Is it that the function that maps A to B can be applied to elements not in A to get elements not in B?

Comment: Not necessarily, but a reduction from $A$ to $B$ is a map $f\colon \mathrm{dom} A \to \mathrm{dom} B$ such that $f(x) \in B$ if and only if $x \in A$, and so for reductions what you wrote could be true.